# Twitter Oauth API 1.1 Error?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

UPDATE: The code works now

So, i'm using [Abraham's Twitter Oauth Library for PHP](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), i download the files and start modifying it (entering consumer key, and consumer secret)

I also have chenged the url to twitter API 1.1's link: `$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";`

But when i open the page, it shows me: `Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.`

Then I `print_r` the `$connection` and got this:

```
TwitterOAuth Object ( [http_code] => 0 [url] => XXX&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=XXX&oauth_version=1.0 [host] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ [timeout] => 30 [connecttimeout] => 30 [ssl_verifypeer] => [format] => json [decode_json] => 1 [http_info] => Array ( [url] => XXX&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=XXX&oauth_version=1.0 [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0.014468 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [redirect_url] => ) [useragent] => TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2 [sha1_method] => OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 Object ( ) [consumer] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => XXX[secret] => XXX[callback_url] => ) [token] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => [secret] => [callback_url] => ) )
```

Anyone knows what is happening?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if there's a firewall blocking sure. Also, make sure that your server time is correctly set.

Comment: AFAIK there is no firewall and the server tiem is correctly set (i'm using free hosting)

Comment: Make sure your application is registered and a callback URL is set.

Comment: actually i have ever used this before, and the code works. But suddenly the code doesn't work (i don't change the code)

Comment: Make sure you recreate the access token after you make changes in your application. Once you've made changes, revoke if you've the app in your user application settings and then try again.